# Android: WebView show blank page when loading url

Tags: java, android, webview

I did an Android app that is basically a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) that loads a url using [loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)).
The problem I have is that when in the app navigation some links the webview says "page not found" but links are ok if you go in a browser.

**Edition: It is not the character the problem I can not determine yet a patron in links that yelds to the error. I only see the mensaje "page finished loading" twice on pages that throws error.**

I tried to catch the moment when the url loads but I do not know how to solve this problem. It only happens on links that are like: http://host/about-us

This is my code of the part that catches the problematic links

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
    if (url.contains("-")) {
        // magic
        Log.i(TAG, "Url contains - ...");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}
```

I got "Url contains - ..." on the logs but I do not know how to get the page open.
If I visit the links on the browser they work perfectly and there is nothing wrong about the urls.

Thanks a lot if anybody can give me a clue of what is going on, I tried many searches before asking.

**Resolved:** It was missing Internet Permission on manifiest file:

I did not realize that everytime I compilate the app and install on my phone the cache remains. The pages I was seeing were in app cache. What I do not know is how the lines that gives internet permission disappear from my manifiest. I use Eclipse IDE do not know if there is a way eclipse overwrites this files.
Thanks for the hints

Comment: have you try to encode url with URLEncoder.encode() ?

Comment: that does not helps as makes my url horrible, it works for parameters, thanks you anyway

Comment: Have your given internet permission in manifest??

Comment: I did Chandru, INTERNET permission is grant as some links works, and others not when I navigate through the site

Comment: Chandru I are rigth I made an edit to comment the solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following to code to check what the error is.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });
```

Comment: 06-05 03:55:28.888: I/MainActivity(9986): Error loading URL: No se pudo conectar al servidor.